# Ruby Mechanize change <select> value that is not in a form

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, mechanize

I have to crawl a page with Mechanize that contains no form tag at all. This page only have some select tag with Javascript bind to onChange event. I need to change these select and have the onChange event fired to be able to read what will appear on the page.

Since Mechanize require to have a form object before accessing field, I'm doomed... Is there a way to access field and change value when there is no form in the page ???

Thx a lot !

Seurdge

Comment: You can access the field without the form but it won't do you any good because mechanize doesn't do anything with javascript events.

Comment: Oh ok you mean that even if I manage to change the values on the select the onChange event will not fire ? So I may look at simething like selenium instead ??

Comment: Ok, I've done it with Watir ! Thx for the cue pguardiaro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a simple Script that use Watir to extract data from the page where there is no form :

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto 'http://www.sitexcom/data.asp'

b.select_list(:id => 'select1').select_value "1"
sleep 2
b.select_list(:id => 'select2').select_value "1"
sleep 2
b.select_list(:id => 'select3').select_value "1"
sleep 4

data = b.table(:id => 'data_table_id')

data.rows.each do |row|
    row.cells.each do |cell|
        puts cell.text
    end
end
```